# Crash after Button Click: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: java, android

I've been searching everywhere for a solution, but ultimately didn't succeed. The Program is supposed to read what's in the TextView (id=textField), then it should display the text with Log.i

Here is MainActivity.java

```
package quotebook.theoneandonly.com.buttons;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public void clickfunction(View view) {
    EditText myTextField = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.textField));
    Log.i("textField Value", myTextField.getText().toString());

}
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

This is the error message I get after I click on the Button:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: quotebook.theoneandonly.com.buttons, PID: 11117
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
                  at quotebook.theoneandonly.com.buttons.MainActivity.clickfunction(MainActivity.java:11)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to cast to the wrong object here. It should be a TextView and not an EditView:

```
EditText myTextField = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.textField));
```

Should be:

```
TextView myTextField = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textField));
```

The relevant error message in this case is the last one in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

Answer (score 0):

'textField' is TextView's ID. You are using it on EditText. 
Check you xml again and change the ID of EditText in MainActivity.

Error log says, TextView cannot be cast to EditText.

Sorry , not enough credits to comment.

Comment: He hadn't posted when I was composing my answer.

Comment: I was typing, I didnt know someone else was going to answer. I posted. I noticed another answer below, which is correct. Well, do you want me to remove this?

Answer (score 0):

it should be like >

```
  EditText myTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textField);
```

remove "()" before casting edit text and end of the line also...i think that's all..problem solved!

Comment: I tried what you suggested, unfortunately i'm still getting the same message.